# Предупреждение после инталляции php5-fpm на ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

Только что установил php5-fpm на ubuntu 12.04. В конце написало предупреждение -

> update-rc.d: warning: php5-fpm stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not
> match LSB Default-Stop values (none)
>      Creating config file /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini with new version

Что это значит? Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установщик попытался добавить в автозапус php-fpm и не указал параметр runlevel.
Так же написано что создан новый конфиг. Если после перезапуска системы php-fpm взлетит, то беспокоиться не стоит об этой надписи.